# Trying to find a more efficient implementation to a small python program

Tags: python, performance, time, coding-efficiency

So I am working through a leetcode problem which asks the following:

Given an array nums of n integers, are there elements a, b, c in nums such that a + b + c = 0? Find all unique triplets in the array which gives the sum of zero.

Note:

The solution set must not contain duplicate triplets.

Example:

Given array `nums = [-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4],`

A solution set is:

```
[
  [-1, 0, 1],
  [-1, -1, 2]
]
```

so I wrote this:

```
class Solution(object):
def threeSum(self, nums):
    
    answer=[]
    length=len(nums)
    
    for i in range(0,length,3):
        for j in range(i+1,length):
            for k in range(j+1,length):
                if nums[i]+nums[j]+nums[k]==0:
                    work=[nums[i],nums[j],nums[k]]
                    answerlen=len(answer)
                    app=1
                    for l in range(answerlen):
                        if sorted(answer[l])==sorted(work):
                            app=0
                            break
               
                    if app==1:
                        answer.append(work)
            
    return answer


d=Solution()
print(d.threeSum([14,4,6,-1,10,9,-8,7,-13,14,-13,-11,-8,-9,11,14,-8,-14,-13,7,-10,-15,-13,-11,-11,11,14,13,2,-14,1,-7,-2,14,-1,-15,9,7,-1,3,6,1,7,5,-1,-5,4,-2,-4,-1,-9,-7,-1,-7,-11,3,12,10,-7,-1,12,1,8,-13,1,14,9,-13,6,-7,-3,-11,2,-11,10,-14,-1,-9,0,2,5,6,3,-11,6,7,0,3,3,0,-12,-8,-13,3,-14,-5,2,10,-11,-14,-12,1,-10,5,5,7,-1,11,14,6,-10,-4,-3,8,-7,10,1,8,-1,-11,-15,-6,-12,-13,12,-11]))
```

The program does what it's supposed to do. However, when it reaches testcases like the one above, I get a Time Limit Exceeded error. This asks me to make my code more efficient and I cannot figure out a better implementation than this one. If anyone can help me understand a better implementation or fix something in my code that I can't see, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look into the functions available in `itertools`. Telling you more will spoil the fun.

Comment: This problem is described here with 3 different methods: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-triplets-array-whose-sum-equal-zero/

Comment: An idea: Create a dict with the numbers as keys and frequencies as values. Outer loop iterates over keys and temporarily decrements frequency. Inner loop the same but skips over keys which already have frequency 0. If you have two elements you already know what the third element must be. So check if it is in dict with frequency >0. Add triple to result if so.

Comment: Also take a look into sets/dictionaries when you're checking for duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.combinations` for solving your problem. It will list all combinations of your list of numbers.

```
possible_combinations = itertools.combinations(num_list, 3)
```

After you have that, you iterate over them checking which ones have a sum equal to 0.

```
sol = [] # list of solutions
for c in possible_combinations:
    if sum(c) == 0:
        sol.append(tuple(sorted(c)))
```

Note that I have sorted the combinations, to get only the unique combinations. After sorting, I converted it into a `tuple`, so we can later hash and eliminate duplicates.

Lastly, to eliminate the duplicates, you can convert your result into a set, which will hash each entry and eliminate duplicates.

```
solutions = set(sol)
```

The complete code, using your `class` is:

```
import itertools


class Solution(object):

    def __init__(self, nums, result=0):
        self.nums = nums
        self.result = result
        self.solutions = []

    def threeSum(self):
        sol = []
        possible_combinations = itertools.combinations(self.nums, 3)
        for c in possible_combinations:
            if sum(c) == self.result:
                sol.append(tuple(sorted(c)))

        self.solutions = set(sol)


num_array = [14, 4, 6, -1, 10, 9, -8, 7, -13, 14, -13, -11, -8, -9, 11, 14, -8, -14, -13, 7, -10, -15, -13, -11, -11, 11, 14, 13, 2, -14, 1, -7, -2, 14, -1, -15, 9, 7, -1, 3, 6, 1, 7, 5, -1, -5, 4, -2, -4, -1, -9, -7, -1, -7, -11, 3, 12, 10, -7, -1, 12, 1, 8, -13, 1, 14, 9, -13, 6, -7, -3, -11, 2, -11, 10, -14, -1, -9, 0, 2, 5, 6, 3, -11, 6, 7, 0, 3, 3, 0, -12, -8, -13, 3, -14, -5, 2, 10, -11, -14, -12, 1, -10, 5, 5, 7, -1, 11, 14, 6, -10, -4, -3, 8, -7, 10, 1, 8, -1, -11, -15, -6, -12, -13, 12, -1]
d = Solution(num_array)
d.threeSum()

print(d.solutions)
```

Comment: I think I missed a chance to use a nice list comprehension there... `[tuple(sorted(c)) for c in possible_combinations if sum(c) == 0]`... oh well..

Answer (score 0):

here is your code

```
from itertools import combinations

data= ([14, 4, 6, -1, 10, 9, -8, 7, -13, 14, -13, -11, -8, -9, 11, 14, -8, -14, -13, 7, -10, -15, -13, -11, -11, 11, 14,
  13, 2, -14, 1, -7, -2, 14, -1, -15, 9, 7, -1, 3, 6, 1, 7, 5, -1, -5, 4, -2, -4, -1, -9, -7, -1, -7, -11, 3, 12,
  10, -7, -1, 12, 1, 8, -13, 1, 14, 9, -13, 6, -7, -3, -11, 2, -11, 10, -14, -1, -9, 0, 2, 5, 6, 3, -11, 6, 7, 0, 3,
  3, 0, -12, -8, -13, 3, -14, -5, 2, 10, -11, -14, -12, 1, -10, 5, 5, 7, -1, 11, 14, 6, -10, -4, -3, 8, -7, 10, 1,
  8, -1, -11, -15, -6, -12, -13, 12, -11])
output = list(set(combinations(data, 3)))
for i in output:
    if sum(i) == 0:
        print(i)
```

Comment: This doesn't account for duplicate triplets. Perhaps you can add something like `output = list(set(output))` to get rid of duplicates.

Comment: simply doing a `set(output)` will not work in this case, because of the order of the solution (it will consider `(1, 2, 3)` different from `(1, 3, 2)`. Look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62579327/8250094) for a complete solution without duplicates.